# Wordpress некоторые картинки битые, не отображаются. Но не все

Tags: html, изображения

Wordpress некоторые картинки битые,  не отображаются.

**Через acf** делал подмену картинок с фоном(идут по умолчанию) на без фона // на страницах, категорий, техника в наличии и пр.

**Подозреваю, из за того что в functions.php** есть такая конструкция// но не факт

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_get_image( $image, $_this, $size, $attr, $placeholder ) {

   $fild=get_field('cat_file', $_this->id);

   if(isset($fild['sizes']['medium'])) {

       $image='<img width="300" height="169" src="'.$fild['sizes']['medium'].'" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">';
    } else {
        $image = $image;
    }


    return $image;
}
```

Очень нужна помощь, никак  не могу понять почему лыжи не едут.

Comment: http://cb04866-wordpress-2.tw1.ru/

Comment: артикул 0096, тоже с битой картинкой http://cb04866-wordpress-2.tw1.ru/vahtovye-avtobusy-ural